# Can't access samba share as another user from same machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba, file-permissions

I am running a home server with Ubuntu 22.04. There are two users on the device A,B

The directories I want to share are

```
/home/A/Pool/ShareA
/home/A/Pool/ShareB
```

Now, when I access the share from a different machine (running Manjaro) as user A, everything works fine. I get an error when I try to access the share as user B

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.11/A-store /mnt/temp -o username=A,password=********
WORKS!
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.11/B-store /mnt/temp -o username=B,password=********

mount error(13): Permission denied
```

I have added the second user to the server (can ssh as B) and used smbpasswd.

I have been looking for hours online to no avail.
Here is my smb.conf

```
[global]
    server role = standalone server
    map to guest = Bad User
    usershare allow guests = yes
    hosts allow = 192.168.1.0/24
    hosts deny = 0.0.0.0/0

[A-store]
        comment = Backup
        path = /home/A/Pool/ShareA
        readonly = no
        guest ok = no
        browsable = yes
        writeable = yes
        valid users = A
        public = no

[B-store]
        comment = Backup for B
        path = /home/A/Pool/ShareB
        readonly = no
        guest ok = yes
        browsable = yes
        writeable = yes
```

/home/A/Pool is a mount-point for a HDD. Why can't I access as user B?

Comment: I have tried using the valid users field for B-store as well, and without authentication I get the following `[sudo] password for local machine: ********** 
Password for root@//192.168.1.11/B-store: *******
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)`

Comment: When working with samba tdbsam password backend, you don't need to set up passwords in the system. Users *should* exist in the OS, but a valid shell and a password is not necessary. Only *samba* password needs to be set, with `sudo smbpasswd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B is not in `valid users` for `B-store`. It is `guest ok`, however; you can mount it without authentication. But anyway, for that the *directory* it resides in, `/home/A/Pool/ShareB`, should have suitable file system permissions for *nobody* (or whoever `guest account` is set to, but in your config it seems to be the default).

*Suitable permissions* means that the user can *traverse* into that directory, which in Linux is achieved by setting at least mode `x` for the user to each parent directory in the path, in this case, `/home`, `/home/A`, `/home/A/Pool`, and at least `r-x` to the final directory, `/home/A/Pool/ShareB`, for the user to be able to read the contents (the listing) of the directory.

Having a directory for user B inside home directory of user A is probably not a good idea. Better flatten the path, and move shared resources *outside* of homes. Also it helps to create a group to control each set of shared resources, make that group into `valid users` (groups are added with @ prefix), and assign shared directory privileges mentioned above to that group. Then you can add all the needed users into that group and they will have the privileges. Useful samba share-level options are `force group` and `force create mode`/`force directory mode`. See `man smb.conf` for details of all parameters mentioned.

Comment: What should be the permissions for /home/A/Pool/ShareB? I have tried setting it to 777 as well without help

Comment: verify that the user who accesses the share (nobody if guest else the user who authenticated to the share) has enough permissions to traverse to that directory, which means it must have at least 'x' mode on all parent directories, `/home`, `/home/A` and `/home/A/Pool`. Generally, it is bad idea to have a directory for user B inside the home of user A, better flatten the path and make something like /home/B.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. I flattened the paths and shared `/home/Pool/ShareA` and `/home/Pool/ShareB`. Everything works as desired. Can you edit the answer with relevant details so it might be helpful to others?